# Can you mock a non static method that calls a static method using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, mockito

I understand you can't mock static methods using mockito. But the method I am trying to mock is not static but it has a call to static methods in it. So can I mock this method?

I get exception when I run the test. Is the call to the static method the reason for this exception?

**The Class to be tested:**

```
public class MyAction{
        public ActionForward search(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            MyService service = new MyService();
            **form.setList(service.getRecords(searchRequest));**
        }
    }
```

**Mocked class and method:**

```
public class MyService{
    public List getRecords(SearchRequest sr){
        List returnList = new ArrayList();
        MyDao dao = DAOFactory.getInstance().getDAO();---->Call to static method
        // Some codes
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

**Class with static method:**

```
public class DAOFactory{
        private static DAOFactory instance = new DAOFactory();

         public static DAOFactory getInstance() {------> The static method
            return instance;
        }       
    }
```

**My Test:**

```
@Test
public void testSearch() throws Exception{
    MyService service = mock(MyService.class);
    MyAction action = new MyAction();

    List<MyList> list = new ArrayList<MyList>();
    when(service.getRecords(searchRequest)).thenReturn(list);
    ActionForward forward = action.search(mapping, form, request, response);        
}
```

This is the stack trace when I run the test. Please keep in mind that I have changed the names of the classes for simplicity. 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your `search` method cannot use the service mock, because it creates its own instance by `MyService service = new MyClass();`. So you must refactor the `MyAction` class to allow `MyService` injection and inject a mock in it. Or use more heavy weapon - PowerMock.

**Easiest and safest Refactoring**

Use in your IDE "extract method" refactoring to extract construction "new MyClass()". So it will become:

```
public class MyAction{
        public ActionForward search(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            MyService service = getMyService();
            **form.setList(service.getRecords(searchRequest));**
        }
        MyService getMyService() {
          return new MyClass();
        }

    }
```

then in your unit test you could inject a mock by creating an inner subclass:

```
public class MyActionTest {
   private MyService service = mock(MyService.class);
   private MyAction action = new MyAction(){
       @Override
       MyService getMyService() {return service;}
   };

    @Test
    public void testSearch() throws Exception{

        List<MyList> list = new ArrayList<MyList>();
        when(service.getRecords(searchRequest)).thenReturn(list);
        ActionForward forward = action.search(mapping, form, request, response);        
    }

}
```

Comment: Doh - there I was looking for more complicated situations, and completely ignoring the fact that the service mock is unused...

Comment: @JonSkeet He-he... He is a *Student*... :)

Comment: Although refactoring is not an option at the moment because I have been asked to write tests for some legacy codes, how would I refactor it so I can inject the mock? Thanks

Comment: @javaStudent I've added one of approaches into my answer

Comment: @kan thank you for your answer. I will try to implement your suggestion. So my next question is mocking a method that calls a static method with Mockito does not create a problem?

Comment: @javaStudent A mocked method is never executed at all, so it doesn't matter what does it to.